# 802.1X Radius WLAN protected by certificate 1024-bit key

Tags: encryption

I want to ask you a question.

I have WPA-2 (enterprise) network. Also called as 802.1x.
I use the Linux Zeroshell distribution, which is optimized for these services. Linux Zeroshell is provides a radius server. I also have a router.
I have entered accounts to Zeroshell, which can access the network. Each human, who wants to connect must have certificate, which I exported and installed to each computer. I there have the options for 1024 or 2048 bit keys. I use 1024 bit keys.
 
Is there connection encrypted by 1024-bit encrypting?
I think it is encrypted by 256-bit encryption and 1024-bit is key for digital signature for each message in LAN?
So is this ''asymmetric'' key used as symetric key?

I am using login based on PEAP + MS CHAP V2.
Certificate is in .PEM format.
Login is only available for WLAN users.

Comment: a) Please don't use 1024-bit keys. It's only a matter (of short) time until they can be broken. b) Please don't export / import private keys. Generate them on the device using them and register the public keys (/ certificates). c) The 1024-bit key correspond to the digital certificates which authenticate you to the router / server in the initial handshake. The transport is 256-bit encrypted (AES).